# Trying to find Java support for SNMPv3 out of the box

Tags: java, snmp

I have an existing script that uses snmpget to query the heap space of a JVM on a machine in our enclave. Recently we've updated all of our SNMP query scripts to use v3. When I went to the JRE documentation about SNMP all I could find was a cursory writeup about communities and ACL config files. That is only applicable to v1 and v2c.

Google is only returning various OSS products that could solve my problem, but I find it hard to believe that JRE 1.8 doesn't allow for answering SNMPv3 queries.

Could somebody please point me to the libraries that support SNMPv3 for JRE 1.8?

Comment: I don't believe this is OT as asking for an off-site resource. The OP is asking about the scope of the Java SE JRE.

Comment: @chrylis And if the answer is 'no' you can only get a slew of two- or three-letter answers saying so, within those terms. Not very useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the documentation only shows you how to expose the JRE instance so that your SNMP tools can monitor it on the network.  Some additional info using JMX here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html  Looks like you'll need a third party API if you want to respond to queries within your code.  Something along the lines of http://www.snmp4j.org/